# How to make selectable text different from what's displayed

Tags: html, css, web-crawler, semantic-markup, screen-readers

I need to create a heavily styled bit of text that doesn't display a specific character visually, but *does* contain the character for other purposes. For example, the UI might show something like `$12345`, but the underlying text is actually `$123.45`.

- If you select the displayed text and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the clipboard should actually contain the underlying text.
- If you select the displayed text and right-click, the context menu should have an option along the lines of `Search Google for "X"` where *X* is the underlying text (assuming the browser supports it).
- Both screen readers and webcrawlers should 'see' the underlying text.

Here's my current solution:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.price {
  line-height: 4.4rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.cc, .cf {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  vertical-align: super;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.cs {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 -.28em;
}

.ci {
  font-size: 4.4rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="price" aria-label="$123.45">
  <span class="cc">$</span><span class="ci">123</span><span class="cs">.</span><span class="cf">45</span>
</span>
```

However, I'm not sure if having an invisible (`opacity: 0`) element is really the best way to do this—it feels a bit underhanded and possibly some smart crawlers may see it that way too. Also, the `-.28em` is not scalable—that's just the best number I could find to look good and I'd have to tweak it for different fonts or font sizes.

I could change the `.cs` to `display: inline-block; width: 0` to get around the `margin` issue, but then if you double-click on the `123` to select the 'word' or triple-click to select the block, the `45` is not selected. So keeping the `.cs` inline seems important to ensuring that the whole text is treated as one continuous piece of text.

So my question is, using HTML5 and CSS, what is the semantically correct way to have different content that gets selected than what's displayed?

Comment: you can use font-size: 0 for the period alone right? wont that work?

Comment: @karthick Actually, it does. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Since the _actual_ page content is `$123.45` that is what screen readers and webcrawlers will see; no need to worry about that. The selection and context menu may be a different issue, but for crawlers and readers the content (not rendering) is king.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font size 0 is an alternative that you can try for the period.

```
.cs {
 font-size: 0;
}
```

The information will be retained as per your requirement both on screen reader and on clipboard